# Several minus signs

Tags: characters

Compare this:

```
- versus -- versus --- versus ---- versus ----- versus ------ \\
\texttt{- versus -- versus --- versus ---- versus ----- versus ------}
```

- In normal Text-Mode, more 'Minus' will just make the line longer. OK.
- But why not when I write 4 Minus signs? Then I get two lines. A longer and a shorter Line. That seems to be a bug for me.
- And in Teletype-Mode with `\texttt{}`

  - 1 Minus leads to 1 Minus
  - 2 Minus leads to 1 Minus
  - 3 Minus leads to 2 Minus
  - 4 Minus leads to 3 Minus
  - 5 Minus leads to 3 Minus
  - 6 Minus leads to 4 Minus

I do not understand this logic. It looks random to me. I would prefer in TeleType-Mode to get two minuses when I enter two minuses. I'm using it for Software documentation. `\texttt{--help}` should lead to `--help`.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Instead of “minus sign” you should say “hyphen”.

Comment: I'm sure there is already and answer on site about this somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This are ligatures. Two hyphen give an endash, three an emdash, and more start this again.

To suppress ligatures you can e.g. use the microtype package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = T1, family = tt* }
\begin{document}
\texttt{--help } 

\textendash:  -- 

\textemdash:  --- 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In OT1 encoding the ligature was off for `tt` by default, at least in my TeXLive 2017... and with T1 I have the en-dash ligature but not the em-dash. Strange...